# couldnot start a service on boot on Vivo Android mobiles

Tags: android

I've been trying to start a service when a device boots up on android,It works on Samsung and Moto mobile but I couldn't get it to work on Vivo and Oppo mobiles. I've looked at online but i could not found any link.

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <receiver
    android:name=".Antitheft.Services.BootComplete"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

 <service
    android:name=".Antitheft.Services.AutoStartUp"
    android:theme="@style/MAppTheme" />
```